Boltzmann distribution in phase space
I am reading the S. Adams' note on mathematical statistical mechanics. The author defined microcanonical measure $\mu$ as the surface measure on the constant energy surface $\Gamma_E $in phase space $\Gamma$. But He did'nt show how to derive the Boltzmann distribution from this, only said that it maximise entropy under the constraint of constant expected value of Hamiltonian.
I read the argument in Peliti's Statistical Mechanics in a Nutshell, which expressed the phase space $\Gamma$ as a product of system $\Gamma_s$ and reservoir $\Gamma_r$ so that $(x_s, x_r ) \in \Gamma = \Gamma_s \times \Gamma_r$. So for a function $f$ depends only on the system variable $x_s$, it's average over $\mu$ is:
$$ \frac{1}{\mu(\Gamma_E)}\int_{\Gamma_E}  f(x_s) d\mu $$
Under the assumption that the reservoir is much larger than the system, the above can be approximated by(using Talyor expansion on Boltzmann entropy):
$$ \frac{1}{Z}\int  f(x_s) e^{-\frac{H_s(x_s)}{k_bT} } dx_s $$
where $H_s(x_s)$ is the Hamiltonian of our system and $Z = \int e^{-\frac{H_s(x_s)}{k_bT} } dx_s $ is the partition function. I'm wondering whether there's any rigorous mathematical version of this proof? Is there any reference?
Also, since $\mu$ is the probability measure(which is uniform) on $\Gamma_E$ that maximizing the entropy, how can I intuitively see that when 'projecting' to the system $\Gamma_s$, the corresponding measure(Boltzmann distribution) also maximizing the entropy but under the constraint of some constant expected value of Hamiltonian?
